# Float <i> to the right of <div> in html

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I want to align this `<i>` to the right side in my `<div>`. This is my html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-1 bg-primary text-white d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
     <h2>Heading</h2>
     <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success ms-3">Welcome</span>
     <i class="fas fa-question-circle" style="float: right;"></i>
</div>
```

The above code is not working. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `i` has to be 1st in your code, or use `position: absolute` instead (and right padding for `div`).

Comment: If I use `position: absolute`, then the `i` will keep changing with change in screen size. I want the `i` to be fixed to the right end of the `div`, irrespective of change in screen size

Comment: Please share output image.

Comment: @ITCMLG don't forget for `position: relative` to parent (div) of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change HTML This Way

```html
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid p-1 bg-primary text-white d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
  <div class="justify-content-center d-flex flex-fill align-items-center">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div>
      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">Welcome</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```